# Will we soon have online IDE that is based on Skywriter?

Tags: javascript, bespin

I saw that Skywriter is released and it looks promising for people that want to create online IDE for other programmers.

Will we soon have online IDE that is based on Skywriter you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not based on Skywriter online IDEs are already here.

One of the most complete ones I've played around with so far is [CodeRun](http://www.coderun.com/).  [Palm's Ares IDE](http://ares.palm.com/Ares/about.html) is also very impressive.

The cool part about Skywriter though is that since it's open source so you can integrate it into your own applications.  You don't need to wait for some new service to make the IDE.  Just throw it up on your own site and edit the pages on the fly.  This is particularly easy with PHP.

Comment: Looks like they recently started a rewrite of the server-side project, so you wont be able to throw it up just yet.